# How can I frame text in Google Colab?

Tags: html, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab notebook, it seems not possible to use `div` and `span` directly in a text cell.
However, I would like to frame text like this:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;"> help </div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Colab notebooks, you are correct that text cells do not support the direct use of HTML tags like `<div>` and `<span>`. However, you can achieve the desired styling using Markdown and HTML attributes within the text cell. Here's how you can frame text using a border and padding:

1. Create a Markdown cell.
2. Use the following Markdown syntax to achieve the desired styling:

```markdown
<div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;">help</div>
```

In this syntax, the `display: inline-block;` style attribute is added to ensure that the `<div>` behaves like an inline element and respects the text flow.

3. Run the Markdown cell to display the framed text.

Keep in mind that while this approach works in Google Colab, the rendering of HTML and CSS styles in Markdown cells might vary across different platforms and environments. Always preview and adjust your content as needed to ensure the desired visual result.